# How do I interact with the Firestore database through the firebase admin?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I can't find the answer to this in the documentation. I have created a firebase cloud function which listens to the database and gets triggered when a doc in the database changes.

What I want the function to do is to gather information from the database, other than the information listened to in the first place, and then work with that information. How would I gather information from the Firestore database using firebase admin?

Down below is the code I have written so far:

```
exports.costCalculation = functions.firestore
  .document("questions/{docId}/post_publish_information/outcome_information")
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const predictions = admin
      .firestore()
      .document("questions/{docId}/post_publish_information/predictions");
    console.log(predictions);
  });
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you shared? Any error message?

Comment: It produces a type error because .document is not a function.

Comment: Same problem as in my answer, it's `doc` not `document`. And same recommendation to keep the reference documentation handy for such errors: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html

Answer (score 0):

The Admin SDK is already loaded and initialized, you just can't access it through the `admin` variable. If you don't feel like initializing an Admin SDK instance yourself, you can work from the document you get it from `change`.

For example, to get a reference to the `predictions` document you can also:

```
change.before.ref.parent.doc("predictions")
```

Comment: That gave me the following error: TypeError: change.before.ref.parent.document is not a function

Comment: Ah yeah, I see it's called `doc`. Updated the code in my answer, but I also recommend you keep the reference documentation handy to most quickly fix such typos: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html